# JTwitter : getStatus()

Tags: java, api, twitter, jtwitter

I'm creating a desktop Twitter client in Java and I'm using JTwitter.
I tested a few lines of code with this library, which seems good, but I'm stuck at one point.
When running my app, Eclipse prints :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

at winterwell.jtwitter.InternalUtils.asMap(InternalUtils.java:170)
at winterwell.jtwitter.Twitter.getStatus(Twitter.java:1646)
at Twittshader.main(Twittshader.java:34)
```

If you want to see the code (oauthClient and twitter objects are declared, I don't think the problem comes from these) :

```
    oauthClient.authorizeDesktop();
    String v = oauthClient.askUser("Please enter the verification PIN from Twitter");causes that.
    oauthClient.setAuthorizationCode(v);
    String[] accessToken = oauthClient.getAccessToken();
    // Works through all the program but crashes at this point
    System.out.println(twitter.getStatus("ShadeosIsaac"));
    twitter.setStatus("Running some tests");
```

I really don't know why it is crashing. I'm pretty sure it is quite a simple thing, but I'm not sure what to do. Ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Can I ask: What version of the JTwitter jar do you have?
You can find this with: `System.out.println(Twitter.version);`